# Elasticsearch Curator

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot, elasticsearch-curator

I am using ElasticSearch Version 1.7.2. I want to take a snapshot with help of the curator. I followed a link get to know that it gives me an incremental snapshot but I didn't get any incremental snapshot of my index.

I have 1 index `test` having 50,000 docs. I have taken a snapshot of that index. After inserting 100,000 docs in the same index, I again took a snapshot of that index. But when I check it, it's showing me the same data in both my snapshots.

What's the difference between those? I don't think it is incremental in any way. Please help me out.

PS: I only want to backup the remaining 100,000, not the whole data.

Output of `GET /_snapshot/my_backup/_all`:

```
{
 "snapshots": [
   {
     "snapshot": "curator-20160509052605",
     "version_id": 1070199,
     "version": "1.7.1",
     "indices": [
        "jal"
     ],
     "state": "SUCCESS",
     "start_time": "2016-05-09T05:26:05.735Z",
     "start_time_in_millis": 1462771565735,
     "end_time": "2016-05-09T05:26:06.282Z",
     "end_time_in_millis": 1462771566282,
     "duration_in_millis": 547,
     "failures": [],
     "shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5
     }
  },
  {
     "snapshot": "curator-20160509055355",
     "version_id": 1070199,
     "version": "1.7.1",
     "indices": [
        "jal"
     ],
     "state": "SUCCESS",
     "start_time": "2016-05-09T05:53:55.824Z",
     "start_time_in_millis": 1462773235824,
     "end_time": "2016-05-09T05:53:56.737Z",
     "end_time_in_millis": 1462773236737,
     "duration_in_millis": 913,
     "failures": [],
     "shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5
     }
  },
  {
     "snapshot": "curator-20160509060002",
     "version_id": 1070199,
     "version": "1.7.1",
     "indices": [
        "jal"
     ],
     "state": "SUCCESS",
     "start_time": "2016-05-09T06:00:02.282Z",
     "start_time_in_millis": 1462773602282,
     "end_time": "2016-05-09T06:00:03.602Z",
     "end_time_in_millis": 1462773603602,
     "duration_in_millis": 1320,
     "failures": [],
     "shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5
     }
   }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: I want only backup of remaining 1,00,000 not whole data.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to improve your spelling and grammar and make it easier to read, and I also included your comment (you can delete it now). Next time please use the editing feature to add additional information to your question instead of adding it via a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not about Curator that takes incremental snapshots, it's about Elasticsearch. And what "incremental" means is not a difference in documents (the data itself). Incremental refers to segments (files) on disk.

Also, Elasticsearch periodically merges segments. Meaning it's taking a series of smaller (or larger) segments of almost the same size and merges them in a bigger segment. After the bigger segment is done being created, ES is deleting the smaller segments.

So, after you added 100000 documents, it's very likely that ES already merged your old segments (the ones containing the first 50k documents) and now the set of segments might be completely new. In this case, of course that the new snapshot almost doesn't contain any old segments.

To really test this, after you are done with your indexing, take a snapshot. Then add 10 documents or so, or change 10 of them, and then take another snapshot. The new snapshot should have a very small size.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have cross checked my new snaopshot has same size as of 50k data i.e, 4.0K. After adding 1lakh data its size is also 4.0K.

Comment: I don't understand your message, sorry. Please reformulate.

Comment: Then you're not actually correctly taking the snapshot. Can't be 4.0K. What commands are you using?

Comment: du -h to check my size of snapshot.

Comment: curator snapshot --repository my_backup indices --all-indices

Comment: Looks good... Can you provide the output of `GET /_snapshot/my_backup/_all`?

Comment: From the list of snapshots, the indices which were snapshoted is only one - `jal`. And you said you want to snapshot an index called `test`. Is this a mistake?

Comment: No, I have change my index name thats it nothing else.

Comment: Did you get any errors of the snapshot operation? Can you try running the [snapshot command without Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-snapshots.html#modules-snapshots)? (directly to Elasticsearch, using the API)

Comment: No,I didn't i have also taken snapshot without curator.I didn't get any type of error.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 "snapshots": [
   {
     "snapshot": "curator-20160509052605",
     "version_id": 1070199,
     "version": "1.7.1",
     "indices": [
        "jal"
     ],
     "state": "SUCCESS",
     "start_time": "2016-05-09T05:26:05.735Z",
     "start_time_in_millis": 1462771565735,
     "end_time": "2016-05-09T05:26:06.282Z",
     "end_time_in_millis": 1462771566282,
     "duration_in_millis": 547,
     "failures": [],
     "shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5
     }
  },
  {
     "snapshot": "curator-20160509055355",
     "version_id": 1070199,
     "version": "1.7.1",
     "indices": [
        "jal"
     ],
     "state": "SUCCESS",
     "start_time": "2016-05-09T05:53:55.824Z",
     "start_time_in_millis": 1462773235824,
     "end_time": "2016-05-09T05:53:56.737Z",
     "end_time_in_millis": 1462773236737,
     "duration_in_millis": 913,
     "failures": [],
     "shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5
     }
  },
  {
     "snapshot": "curator-20160509060002",
     "version_id": 1070199,
     "version": "1.7.1",
     "indices": [
        "jal"
     ],
     "state": "SUCCESS",
     "start_time": "2016-05-09T06:00:02.282Z",
     "start_time_in_millis": 1462773602282,
     "end_time": "2016-05-09T06:00:03.602Z",
     "end_time_in_millis": 1462773603602,
     "duration_in_millis": 1320,
     "failures": [],
     "shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5
     }
   }
 ]
 }
```